# Entity Framework Core is not creating tables in my databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

I've tried deleting and creating a new database, deleting and creating new migrations, and can't get anything to work.

First, I created a new database, then put the connection string in appsettings, and tried to run "update-database". All I got was this:

```
Executed DbCommand (178ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
Executed DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',    CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
ORDER BY [MigrationId];
Done.
```

And nothing was created. So, I deleted everything and started from scratch, then I got this:

```
Executed DbCommand (141ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
Executed DbCommand (20ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
ORDER BY [MigrationId];
Applying migration '20181220145036_test'.
Executed DbCommand (49ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [CartItems] (
    [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [cartID] nvarchar(max),
    [itempicture] nvarchar(max),
    [name] nvarchar(max),
    [price] int NOT NULL,
    [productID] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CartItems] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'CartItems' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:2170e7ba-871f-416a-88c9-bfb2bf586d3d
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'CartItems' in the database.
```

And I know this is wrong because it's a brand new, empty database. Some of my code:

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                 .Build();

            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
    }

    //protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    //{
    //    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    //    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    //    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    //    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    //}

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CartItems> CartItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

CartItems:

```
public class CartItems
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string cartID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public string itempicture { get; set; }
    public int productID { get; set; }
}
```

I've been able to create tables with this same code and application in the past. I also use EFCore the same way in other projects currently without any issues. So, I'd really appreciate some help in getting this back working again. I'd like to know what to do about this in the future.

**Edit:** connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=CHRISTOPHER09E8;Initial Catalog=LNCTest;Integrated Security=True"
```

**EDIT2:** Migration:

```
namespace LNCLibrary.Migrations
{
    public partial class Initialv1 : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "CartItems",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    cartID = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    itempicture = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    price = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    productID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_CartItems", x => x.ID);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Products",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Category = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    DateCreated = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    GenderOption = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Price = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    ProductDescription = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ProductName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ProfilePicture = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Quantity = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Products", x => x.ID);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Address = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    CheckoutComments = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    City = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    State = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    ZipCode = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Value = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Size",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    ProductID = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                    ThisSize = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Size", x => x.ID);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Size_Products_ProductID",
                        column: x => x.ProductID,
                        principalTable: "Products",
                        principalColumn: "ID",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Orders",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Address = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    CartID = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    CheckoutComments = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    City = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ConfirmationNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    DateOfPurchase = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    FinalPrice = table.Column<float>(nullable: false),
                    FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PaymentMethod = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    RegularCustomerId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    State = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Status = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    ZipCode = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    isGuest = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Orders", x => x.ID);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Orders_AspNetUsers_RegularCustomerId",
                        column: x => x.RegularCustomerId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "OrderDetails",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    CartID = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    OrderID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    price = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    productpicture = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_OrderDetails", x => x.ID);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_OrderDetails_Orders_OrderID",
                        column: x => x.OrderID,
                        principalTable: "Orders",
                        principalColumn: "ID",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Orders_RegularCustomerId",
                table: "Orders",
                column: "RegularCustomerId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_OrderDetails_OrderID",
                table: "OrderDetails",
                column: "OrderID");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Size_ProductID",
                table: "Size",
                column: "ProductID");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "EmailIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedEmail");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                column: "RoleId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "CartItems");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "OrderDetails");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Size");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Orders");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Products");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I know this is 3 years later. That the ```dotnet``` commoand can't find your application settings is a known issue. You have to create a workaround, like copying your application settings file, hard code the connection string, or the like. According to Microsoft, they will have a solution in .Net 7 .. sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, thanks to u/The_MAZZTer on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/a8007d/im_having_an_issue_with_efcore_in_my_aspnet_core/). So, for some reason the Configuration Builder in the `OnConfiguration` method in my `ApplicationDbContext` is not finding the connection string in my `appsettings.json`. Something is going wrong there. I hardcoded the connection string in to the method and pushed the migration to my databases without any issues. So now I need to figure out if there's a way around using this method, or a way to figure out why it's not pulling the right string. Nevertheless, I now have a way to migrate, and that's what's important to me right now. Thanks everyone else for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have no need to create the database manually. Update-database command do all the things.

Comment: So you're saying the connection string should just be pointing to the SQL server, not the database?

Comment: Yes! But you also need to mention the database name. It will generate the database by itself.
Your connection should something like: `"Default": "server=.; database=WebApiSample; Trusted_Connection=true"` 
You have no need to create the WebApiSample database. It will generate one.

Comment: Okay, I was not aware of that. I will give that a try.

Comment: So, I deleted the DB, created a new name for the db in my connection string, deleted the migrations and created a new one, and still got the same error:
There is already an object named 'CartItems' in the database. I'll add my connection string to the post.

Comment: You have dleeted all the migrations file and create new migration. Right?
What you got on that migration file?

Comment: Yeah, I deleted all migrations.

Comment: Added new Migration code. Restarted VS as well and got the same error.

Comment: Did you checkout your database after running the cammand. It creates any table or not?

Comment: Nope, no tables or database created.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, everything was ok except connection string. But build went ok so I didn't look at it in the beginning.

This is how my connection string looked on the end in `appsettings.json` since my MS SQL server was working on specific port:

```
 "AuthDbContextConnection": "Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,10008;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sqluser;Password=sqlpassword"
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is here instead of IP address.

### Full steps of adding identity to existing ASP.NET MVC Core 3.x project

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-without-existing-authorization) MS tutorial for adding Identity to ASP.NET MVC Core 3.x project and I had some problems as you so I show here how they were resloved.

I wasn't able to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore` so I went on packet page [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.entityframeworkcore/) and installed latest version for my project (.NET Core 3.x) which is [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.10). So I've installed package with :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 3.1.10
```

After that I run

```
Add-Migration CreateIdentitySchema -Context AuthDbContext
```

It didn't work without context parameter.
This created 2 migrations which I ran separately:

```
Update-Database 20201217102436_InitialCreate -Context AuthDbContext
```

and than

```
 Update-Database 20201218083037_CreateIdentitySchema -Context AuthDbContext
```

And that worked. Tables were created in MS SQL server successfully.

Comment: Just as a heads up, when I had first asked this question this was a .Net Core 1.1 project.